# Find the Twitter text box element with python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I made my own Twitter complaint bot that tweets at my ISP if the network drops.
Code works perfect, until it has to find the Twitter textbox to type the tweet.
Main error is:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I have tried:

- Adding time delays
- Using Firefox Driver instead of Google
- Adding page refreshes before the tweet_at_provider() looks for the textbox
- Clicking the "Tweet" button to bring up the textbox to then try type in it
- Using find.element_by_id but twitter changes id every pageload

When I comment out the first function call to test, it will find and type 6/10 times.
But when both functions are called the tweet_at_provider() always fails at grabbing the textbox and I get the StaleElement error.

```
import selenium, time, pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException, NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException


PROMISED_DOWN = 200
PROMISED_UP = 10
CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = "C:\Development\chromedriver.exe"
GECKODRIVER_PATH = "C:\\Users\\meeha\\Desktop\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe"
TWITTER_USERNAME = "my_username"
TWITTER_PASSWORD = "my_password"


class InternetSpeedTwitterBot():

    def __init__(self, driver_path):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
        self.down = 0
        self.up = 0

    def get_internet_speed(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.speedtest.net/")
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(2)
        go = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/a/span[4]")
        go.click()
        time.sleep(40)

        self.down = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/span")
        self.up = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/span")

        print(f"Download Speed: {self.down.text} Mbps")
        print(f"Upload Speed: {self.up.text} Mbps")
        time.sleep(3)

    def tweet_at_provider(self):
        self.driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(3)
        username = self.driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]")
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_name("session[password]")
        username.send_keys(TWITTER_USERNAME)
        password.send_keys(TWITTER_PASSWORD)
        password.submit()
        time.sleep(5)

        tweet_compose = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/header/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/a/div/span/div/div/span/span')
        tweet_compose.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        textbox = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div')
        textbox.send_keys(f"Hey @Ask_Spectrum, why is my internet speed {self.down.text} down / {self.up.text} up when I pay for {PROMISED_DOWN} down / {PROMISED_UP} up???")


bot = InternetSpeedTwitterBot(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)

bot.get_internet_speed()
bot.tweet_at_provider()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error there and figured out that HTML tag was instantly changing as soon as I was typing something on the twitter text-box.

tackle this problem using XPATH of span tag that was showing up after typing space from my side. break 
 tag is the initial tag when there is not any text prompted by you, only after you type anything 
 turns into  and that's when you have to copy XPATH and use it for your application

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Search by Class name, instead of XPath.

change last 5 lines to the following:

```
#First line is all that you need =)
tweet_compose=self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'br[data text="true"]')
tweet_compose.send_keys(f"Yak Yak {self.down} {self.up}...")
```

Answer (score 0):

for me I used a solution where you click on the text area and then write something using library called Pyautogui which simulates writing on keyboard
here is an example

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pyautogui
# Initialize Chrome WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


editor_field = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[class="DraftEditor-editorContainer"]')
editor_field.click()
# Wait for a few seconds before typing
time.sleep(5)

# Type "hello twitter" with a 0.1-second interval between each keypress
pyautogui.typewrite('hello twitter', interval=0.1)
time.sleep(5)
post_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//span[text()="Post"]')
post_button.click()
time.sleep(15)

#editor_field.send_keys('any')
time.sleep(30)
driver.quit()
```